# Arduino Yun not getting response from Azure API

Tags: arduino-yun, web-service

I posted this on StackOverflow but figured I'd post it here too. Sorry in advance if thats not allowed.

I'm trying to get my Arduino Yun to talk to an API that I'm hosting on Azure. I would like to do more complex things in the future, but at the moment I'm just trying to make a GET request over wifi with a single integer as a parameter.

I'm basically just using the example found [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LibraryExamples/HttpClient) with the url changed. The example works fine, so as far as I'm aware the issue isn't with my board, its with the interaction with Azure.

HttpClient.get() returns an int as a response (not the regular HTTP response codes, its unique for the library). I got 60 initially, and changing my API to accept http calls (instead of just https) fixed this and made me get a response of 0 instead. 0 is the same response that I get from the working Arduino example, but for some reason I'm not actually getting anything in the body of my response, as the client.available() loop is never entered.

The API works as intended when I go to the url in chrome, so the issue arises somewhere due to how the arduino and azure talk to each other, but I don't know enough about either to figure it out and nowhere that I look seems to point me in the right direction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, even though I set azure to accept http requests, it was still redirecting to https which the arduino couldn't handle. I've written a python script to offload the requests to the linux processor, and now it works.